# UICollectionView cannot be scrolled

Tags: ios, swift

I added UICollectionView in view, and it not scroll.

```
private func addFriendCollectionView() {
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 90, height: 50)

    let positionRectangle = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: (mainContainerView?.frame.width)!, height: 100)

    friendsCollection = UICollectionView(frame: positionRectangle, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    friendsCollection?.registerClass(FriendCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "friendCell")
    friendsCollection?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    friendsCollection?.dataSource = self
    friendsCollection?.delegate = self

    self.mainContainerView?.addSubview(friendsCollection!)
}
```

But if i change

```
private func addFriendCollectionView() {
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 90, height: 50)

    let positionRectangle = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: (mainContainerView?.frame.width)!, height: 100)

    friendsCollection = UICollectionView(frame: positionRectangle, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    friendsCollection?.registerClass(FriendCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "friendCell")
    friendsCollection?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    friendsCollection?.dataSource = self
    friendsCollection?.delegate = self
// Add collection view to root view 
    self.view.addSubview(friendsCollection!)
}
```

All work fine.

How to add scroling to UICollectionView? Follow code show how to container view

```
private func addBackGroundView() {
    let imageRect = CGRect(x: 5, y: 70, width: self.view.frame.width - 10, height: self.view.frame.height - 75)
    backGroundImage = InviteFriendsBackGroundImageView(frame: imageRect)
    backGroundImage!.image = InviteFriendsData.sharedInstance.image

    self.view.addSubview(backGroundImage!)
}

private func addMainContainerView() {
    let mainContainerPosition = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: self.view.frame.width - 10, height: self.view.frame.height - 80)

    mainContainerView = UIView(frame: mainContainerPosition)
    mainContainerView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    backGroundImage?.addSubview(mainContainerView!)
}
```